# AngularJS resource and python-bottle

Tags: angularjs, parameters, parameter-passing, bottle

I have a Javascript object. It's a dictionnary with various fields. I want to pass it to my Server, in python-bottle.

Coffeescript:

```
Process = $resource('/collections/processImage')
res = Process.get {vpict}
```

Python-bottle:

```
@app.route('/collections/processImage', method='GET')   
def processImage(db):
vpict = request.query.decode()
```

I can't get a correct object. I've tried request.query.get without more luck.
At best, I get a string which is the JSON representation of my object !

However, if I add:

```
 data = json.load(vpict)
```

I got my JSON object but I feel it is the wrong way to do.

Am I doing things the right / best way ?

Thanks !

Comment: What "correct object" would you like to get?  Want to help but I'm not clear on what you expect `vpict` or `data` to be.

Comment: Under coffeescript, vpict is a dictionnary like {'path':'....', 'id':1242, 'size':'1024}. I want to get the same object on the Python side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

Coffee:

```
Process = $resource('/collections/processImage',{},{do:{method:'POST'}})
Process.do {'img':vpict}
```

Python-bottle:

```
@app.route('/collections/processImage', method='POST')  
def processImage(db):
vpict = request.json['img']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried `data = request.json()`?

(That's the "official" way of getting an `application/json` request's body as JSON.)

Comment: Yes. Did not work. I think request.json() only works for POST request. Here, it's a GET request.

Comment: I will move to a POST request rather a GET. Since the object can be be big, POST will be a better option.